# tools:showIn causing error in Android layout

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

I've searched through the site but haven't found a similar question. I have finished making this layout, and then I proceeded to make some changes in my code (not regarding the layout), and when I came back to content_main.xml, the layout decided not to render. The solution seems to be when I remove this line:

```
tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main"
```

Then the layout renders, of course, without the toolbar. The layout is slightly complicated, but it worked fine up until now, and I haven't changed anything in the toolbar layout. Where should I look? In the content_main.xml,activity_main, or where? Also, I can post whatever piece of code might be relevant to this problem. But I do not know what is relevant and what isn't, so instead of posting 500 xml lines of code, (plus 2600 lines in java), I'm not going to post until someone tells me what might be the problem.

**EDIT**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context="com.example.samprocreativecenter.nfc.MainActivity"

    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:background="#819fba">
    <!-- tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main"
     -->
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:background="@drawable/ekran"
        android:clickable="false">
   <TextView
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="0dp"
       android:layout_weight="1"
       android:gravity="end"
       android:id="@+id/txtStatus"
       android:textColor="#ffffff"/>
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="3"
        android:textSize="28sp"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:id="@+id/editUnos"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-thin"
        android:gravity="bottom|end"
        />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:id="@+id/layoutTasteri"
        android:orientation="vertical">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1">
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:id="@+id/img1"
            android:src="@drawable/p1"/>
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:id="@+id/img2"
            android:src="@drawable/p2"/>
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:id="@+id/img3"
            android:src="@drawable/p3"/>
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1">
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:id="@+id/img4"
            android:src="@drawable/p4"/>
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:id="@+id/img5"
            android:src="@drawable/p5"/>
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:id="@+id/img6"
            android:src="@drawable/p6"/>
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        >
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:id="@+id/img7"
            android:src="@drawable/p7"/>
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:id="@+id/img8"
            android:src="@drawable/p8"/>
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:id="@+id/img9"
            android:src="@drawable/p9"/>
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1">
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:id="@+id/imgNazad"
            android:src="@drawable/delete"/>
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:id="@+id/img0"
            android:src="@drawable/p0"/>
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:id="@+id/imgEnter"
            android:src="@drawable/enter"/>
    </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="30dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:src="@drawable/linija"/>
   <LinearLayout
       android:layout_width="0dp"
       android:layout_height="match_parent"
       android:layout_weight="1"
       android:visibility="gone"
       android:id="@+id/layoutOtvorenListView"
       android:orientation="vertical">
       <TextView
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="18dp"
           android:id="@+id/txtSmanjiListView"
           android:background="#607b9a"
           android:text="Info panel"
           android:textColor="#d9e8e7"/>
       <ListView
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:id="@+id/listViewOtvoreni"
           android:stackFromBottom="true">
       </ListView>
   </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:id="@+id/layoutSredina">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="vertical">
            <TextClock
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:textSize="60sp"
                android:id="@+id/textClock"
                android:textColor="#ffffff"/>
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="27sp"
                android:id="@+id/txtDatum"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:textColor="#ffffff"
                android:fontFamily="sans-serif-thin"/>
        </LinearLayout>
        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:id="@+id/layoutSredinaPodesavanja"
            android:visibility="gone"
            >
            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:id="@+id/imgUspesnaVerifikacija"
                />
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:text="Domen"
                android:id="@+id/domen"
                android:textColor="#ffffff"
                android:textSize="12sp"/>
            <EditText
                android:layout_below="@+id/domen"
                android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="27dp"
                android:textColor="#ffffff"
                android:background="@drawable/unos_polje_neaktivno"
                android:textColorHint="#a6bbce"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:maxLines="1"
                android:id="@+id/editDomen"/>
            <TextView
                android:layout_below="@+id/editDomen"
                android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/server"
                android:text="Adresa servera"
                android:textColor="#ffffff"
                android:textSize="12sp"/>
            <EditText
                android:layout_below="@+id/server"
                android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="27dp"
                android:background="@drawable/unos_polje_neaktivno"
                android:textColor="#ffffff"
                android:maxLines="1"
                android:textColorHint="#a6bbce"
                android:id="@+id/editServer"/>

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="100dp"
                    android:layout_height="40dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="end"
                    android:id="@+id/imgVerifikacija"
                    android:src="@drawable/verifikacija"
                    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"/>

        </RelativeLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1.7"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:id="@+id/layoutSredinaDole"
            android:visibility="visible">
            <Spinner
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:id="@+id/spnMestoTroska"
                android:spinnerMode="dropdown"
                android:layout_gravity="start"
                >
            </Spinner>
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="120dp"
                android:layout_height="70dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:background="@drawable/mesto_troska"
                android:id="@+id/txtSpinner"
                />
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="18dp"
                android:background="@drawable/rsz_prologin_pocetna_1"
                android:id="@+id/txtListView"/>
            <ListView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/listView">

            </ListView>
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:id="@+id/layoutDesniPodesavanja"
        android:visibility="gone"
        >
        <TextView
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
            android:text="Rezim sinhronizacije"
            android:textSize="13sp"
            android:textColor="#a6bbce"
            android:id="@+id/rezim"/>
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
            android:textSize="13sp"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:id="@+id/txtSinhronizacija"
            android:layout_below="@+id/rezim"/>
        <ImageView
            android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
            android:layout_width="55dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/rezim"
            android:id="@+id/imgSinhronizuj"
            android:src="@drawable/sinhronizuj"
            />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/imgSinhronizuj"
            android:textSize="9sp"
            android:text="Sinhronizuj"
            android:layout_alignStart="@+id/imgSinhronizuj"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:id="@+id/sinhronizuj"
            />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Rezim rada terminala:"
            android:textColor="#a6bbce"
            android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
            android:textSize="13sp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/sinhronizuj"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            android:id="@+id/rezimrada"
            />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/txtTipRV"
            android:layout_below="@+id/rezimrada"
            android:layout_alignStart="@+id/rezimrada"
            android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            />
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="55dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_marginEnd="15dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
            android:id="@+id/imgOdustani"
            android:src="@drawable/odustani" />
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="55dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="15dp"
            android:id="@+id/imgSacuvaj"
            android:src="@drawable/snimi"/>
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/txtKoristiMT"
            android:layout_below="@+id/txtTipRV"
            android:layout_alignStart="@+id/txtTipRV"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/txtGPS"
            android:layout_below="@+id/txtKoristiMT"
            android:layout_alignStart="@+id/txtKoristiMT"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/txtSlika"
            android:layout_below="@+id/txtGPS"
            android:layout_alignStart="@+id/txtGPS"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/txtDozTestaturu"
            android:layout_below="@+id/txtSlika"
            android:layout_alignStart="@+id/txtSlika"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            />
        </RelativeLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:id="@+id/layoutDesni"
        android:visibility="visible">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.9">
            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:id="@+id/imgDolazak"
                android:src="@drawable/dolazak"/>
            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:id="@+id/imgOdlazak"
                android:src="@drawable/odlazak"/>
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.6">
            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
               android:layout_height="match_parent"
               android:layout_weight="1"
                android:id="@+id/imgPauza"
                android:src="@drawable/pauza"/>
            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:id="@+id/imgTeren"
                android:src="@drawable/rad_teren"/>
            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:id="@+id/imgPrivatno"
                android:src="@drawable/privatno"/>
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.3">
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="Pauza"
                android:textColor="#ffffff"
                android:textSize="10sp"
                android:src="@drawable/pauza"
                android:gravity="center"/>
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:src="@drawable/rad_teren"
                android:text="Rad na terenu"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:textColor="#ffffff"
                android:textSize="10sp"/>
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:src="@drawable/privatno"
                android:text="Privatno odsutan"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:textColor="#ffffff"
                android:textSize="10sp"/>
        </LinearLayout>
        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1.17">
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">
                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="70dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                    android:id="@+id/imgView"
                    android:layout_marginStart="5dp"/>
                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:layout_marginStart="1dp">
                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="0dp"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:textColor="#a6bbce"
                        android:text="Poslednji prijavljeni"
                        android:textSize="12sp"/>
                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="0dp"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:id="@+id/txtPoslenjiUpisani"
                        android:textColor="#ffffff"
                        android:text=""
                        android:textSize="12sp"/>
                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="0dp"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:textColor="#a6bbce"
                        android:text="Pozicija"
                        android:textSize="12sp"/>
                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="0dp"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:id="@+id/txtPoslednjeMestoTroska"
                        android:textColor="#ffffff"
                        android:text=""
                        android:textSize="12sp"/>
                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="0dp"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:textColor="#a6bbce"
                        android:text="Vreme"
                        android:textSize="12sp"/>
                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="0dp"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:textColor="#ffffff"
                        android:id="@+id/txtPoslenjeVreme"
                        android:text=""
                        android:textSize="12sp"/>
                </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>

            <TextureView
                android:layout_width="0.1dp"
                android:layout_height="0.1dp"
                android:id="@+id/texture"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                />
        </RelativeLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.6"
            android:layout_marginTop="4dp">
            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="0.9"
                android:id="@+id/imgScrollLevo"
                android:src="@drawable/levo"/>
        <HorizontalScrollView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
            android:layout_weight="5"
            android:id="@+id/horScrollView"
            android:gravity="center">
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:id="@+id/layoutZaposleni"
                android:orientation="horizontal">
            </LinearLayout>
        </HorizontalScrollView>
            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="0.9"
                android:id="@+id/imgScrollDesno"
                android:src="@drawable/desno"/>
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

And yes, I am aware that nested weights can be an issue, but this is still a test build. All the drawables exist and work.

Comment: add your whole layout in here

Comment: I had the same problem with `showIn`